# При отправке PUT запроса получаю 400

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, http-status-code-400

Я использую пакет json-server с портом на 3000, npm start запущен на 3001 порте.

Проблема: при попытке отправки объекта в dump.json вылетает 400, но занимательно, что GET запрос возвращает 200 и я получаю данные которые указал.

Проблемный код:

```
const handleAddTodo = (id) => {
    const newTodo = {
        id: 3,
        title: "test"
    };

    const options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }

    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/todos/3',
        {
            ...options,
            body: newTodo
        })
        .then(() => setTodos([...todos, newTodo]));
}
```

Консоль браузера chrome:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/todos/3 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: Не 404, а 400. Чините ваш бекенд

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, 404 правил на 400, я не бекенд разработчик, поэтому не знаю где чинить, до этого проекта на другом компьютере все работало

Comment: А что в логах  json-server?

Comment: Попробуйте `JSON.strigify(newTodo)`

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы, оказалось я не использовал нет тот метод запроса(PUT), когда для одиночного 'todo', мне нужен был POST метод.